# When using profile, get error "snakemake: error: Couldn't parse config file: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'safe_load'"

Tags: python, snakemake

On snakemake 7.29.0, running `snakemake --profile profiles/basel-combined-cluster` I get the following error:

```
snakemake: error: Couldn't parse config file: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'safe_load'
```

I tried `--verbose` and `--debug`, neither of which helped. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a recently reported [bug](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/2326) in snakemake 7.29.0.

Downgrading to 7.28.3 or upgrading to 7.30.0 fixes it.